# I can't figure out why this code is an infinite loop

Tags: python, python-3.x

Here is my code that I ran in spyder:

```
#continue keyword
i=0
while i<10:
    if i==5:
        continue
    print(i)
    i=i+1
    #dont forget to increment i
    #otherwise it becomes infinity loop
```

first it produced output like[image]

then I stoped the current running program
with KeyboardInterrupt

question is why my loop runned infinitly[image]

Comment: After i becomes 5, it never gets incremented, It will become infinte loop

Comment: This has nothing to do with `spyder`. In any event -- what did you expect to happen? Perhaps you are confusing `continue` and `break`

Comment: why it is not incremented when i becomes 5

Comment: Your `continue` causes the code to skip the rest of that iteration and move on to the next iteration. It is not incrementing because you told it not to (though you may not have realized that)

Comment: On further thought, you were (in effect) confusing `continue` with `pass` rather than `break`

Comment: tq for all i got the solution now I got it .thanks i love this StackOverflow

Answer (score 2):

After i becomes 5, it never gets incremented, It will become infinte loop.
If you want to print everything else other than 5

```
i=0
while i<10:
    if i!=5:
       print(i)
    i=i+1
```

Comment: Your first code is still an infinite loop, and in the second one there is no real effect of the `continue`...

Comment: @Tomerikoo The first code had indentation problem. Thanks for pointing it out, corrected

Answer (score 1):

> The continue statement is used to skip the rest of the code inside a
> loop for the current iteration only. Loop does not terminate but
> continues on with the next iteration.

https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/break-continue

So.. i is always 5, because continue makes python always skip i = i + 1